# Timestamp Update Using Formula in Excel But Different Sheet

Tags: excel-formula

For Timestamp Update Formula:

```
=IF(B4<>"",IF(AND(F4<>"",CELL("address")=ADDRESS(ROW(B4),COLUMN(F4))),NOW(),IF(CELL("address")<>ADDRESS(ROW(B4),COLUMN(B4)),F4,NOW())),"")
```

This works fine when it is on the same sheet, but it's not working for different sheets, even after changing the all of the `B4` references into `Sheet1!B4` and looking at the output in the Sheet 2 in F4 Cell.

I want my result to be in Sheet 2 where data will be enter in Sheet 1

Comment: what does `B4″”` and `F4″”` represent in your formula? The double quotation marks you used in your formula should be `"` but not `”` by the way.

Comment: =IF(B4<>"",IF(AND(F4<>"",CELL("address")=ADDRESS(ROW(B4),COLUMN(F4))),NOW(),IF(CELL("address")<>ADDRESS(ROW(B4),COLUMN(B4)),F4,NOW())),"")

Comment: @TerryW, I updated my code, could u please give me the solution?

Comment: can you please confirm, the `B4` and `F4` you plan to use in your new formula, which one is on `Sheet1` and which one is on `Sheet2`? Even better, if you can show some sample data from your `Column B` and `Column F` and demonstrate the expected result that will make it easier for people to understand your problem.